# Combine Context Providers in React

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I'm building an application with Typescript in React.
I've got multiple Context providers. return function in App.tsx looks like this:

```
    return (
        <>
            <AuthenticationProvider>
                <SubscriptionsProvider>
                    <ResourceProvider>
                        <ResourceAggregatesProvider>
                            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                                <Router>
                                    <main>
                                        <Routes>
                                            ...
                                        </Routes>
                                    </main>
                                </Router>
                            </ThemeProvider>
                        </ResourceAggregatesProvider>
                    </ResourceProvider>
                </SubscriptionsProvider>
            </AuthenticationProvider>
        </>
    )
```

Now I want to reduce the Providers by outsourcing them to something like an `AppContextProvider.tsx` so that the return function in `App.tsx` reduces to something like:

```
    return (
        <>
            <AppContextProvider> # Contains AuthenticationProvider, SubscriptionsProvider, ResourceProvider and ResourceAggregatesProvider
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <Router>
                        <main>
                            <Routes>
                                ...
                            </Routes>
                        </main>
                    </Router>
                </ThemeProvider>
            </AppContextProvider>
        </>
    )
```

I tried [this tutorial](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-combine-context-providers-for-cleaner-react-code-9ed24f20225e) but ended up with the following error:
`TS2559: Type '{ children: any; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.` within the CombineComponents.tsx

How is this normally managed in a real environment?

Comment: Are you using React 18?

Comment: @anthony-ma Yes, I am using React 18.2.0

Comment: React 18 famously removed `children` from `React.FC`, you now have to explicitly provide the `children` prop: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-react-fc-children-prop-in-react-18-with-typescript-6ab7b2c901ce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return of `App.tsx`:

```
return (
    <AppContextProvider> # Wraps Context providers
        <Router>
            <main>
                <Routes>
                    ...
                </Routes>
            </main>
        </Router>
    </AppContextProvider>
)
```

Instead of listing all the context providers in the App.tsx, I keep it clean and have all the providers in a separate `AppContextProvider`:

```
const AppContextProvider: FC<Children> = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <AuthenticationProvider>
            <SubscriptionsProvider>
                <ResourceProvider>
                    <ResourceAggregatesProvider>
                        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                            {children}
                        </ThemeProvider>
                    </ResourceAggregatesProvider>
                </ResourceProvider>
            </SubscriptionsProvider>
        </AuthenticationProvider>
    );
};

export default AppContextProvider;
```

`Children.d.ts`:

```
export type Children = {
    children?: React.ReactNode
}
```